# Electrical two prong wiring / gfi swap

Tags: wiring, gfci

I purchased an old home with partial knob and tube. Previous owners changed out all two prong outlets with GFI's.   All of the outlets outlets are reading hot and neutral reversed.

Is this fix as simple as going to each outlet and swapping the wires?

Answer (score 1):

If the wiring was indeed two wire, there should not be a ground. Without a ground, your 3-light tester cannot detect hot/neutral reversal, it can only report open-ground.

Unless they pulled a new ground to the outlets (unlikely), then someone wired a bootleg ground (wire from neutral to ground) and connected it wrong! This is very dangerous. Pull out the outlet and if there is a bootleg, remove it. Your GFCI outlet is legal without an existing ground, assuming it is labeled "No ground".

If you need to verify the hot/neutral wiring, you'll need to run a wire from a grounded object (water plumbing, for example) to the pigtail of a 3-to-2-pin outlet adapter and plug your tester into that.

Answer (score -2):

Take out one outlet.  if that has the hot and neutral wires reversed, it's a pretty good bet the others the tester has flagged are the same.

Switch the wires. You should be good to go, unless you see some other issue that the tester doesn't pick up.

Post a pic here of the wiring for a more concise answer.

Comment: This answer is very dangerous as it is failing to address the likely bootleg ground issue.

Comment: @nobody, We don't know that the ground was improper. Asking the OP to post a pic of the wiring was to remove speculation and be able to answer based on what is there.  "... unless you see some other issue that the tester doesn't pick up." Is verbage that indicates there could be other issues, (ground).